# How do I know when a session is migrated from one JVM to another?

Tags: session, servlets, distributed, servlet-listeners

Which listener do I use to get notified when a session is migrated from one JVM to another?

With HttpSessionActivationListener I can get when a session is activated (sessionDidActivate) and passitivated (sessionWillPassivate) but from there, how do I get if it is another JVM or the same JVM and another session?

Comment: I am not aware of an API, but have you tried to use a session attribute containing the hostname? This way you could detect a change by comparing the session attribute's value with the real hostname.